# How to install Scoop in Google Colab?

Tags: powershell, google-colaboratory, scoop-installer

the github page of [Scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop#installation) has installation instructions for Windows using Powershell (which I successfully did) but for Colab which supports python (or one can use %%Bash for cmd commands), is there a way to use Powershell commands on Colab like cmd. To be precise this is the command I need to execute:

```
Invoke-Expression (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://get.scoop.sh')

# or shorter
iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoop only runs on Windows. But Google Colab is Ubuntu linux.

So, you cannot use it in Colab.